# How to use Type?

Tags: typescript

There is type:

```
type Filter  =  {
    <T>(array: T[], f: (item: T) => boolean): T[]
}
```

And concrete variable with type:

```
let filter: Filter;
```

I have tried to use it like:

```
filter([1,2,3], _ => _ > 2);
```

I got this error:

> Variable 'filter' is used before being assigned.

Also I tried this:

```
let filter: Filter = ([1,2,3], _ => _ > 2);
```

Also  I wonder what does it mean: `_ => _ > 2` and why `_` instead anothre one symbol?

For exmaple there is a realization:

```
function filter(array, f) {
}
```

How to bind this realizaton with concrete filter type?

Comment: `let filter: Filter;` just declares variable, you should assign a value to it (something that "implements" this "contract")

Comment: Owww, yes, I frotgor this, sorry, question can be closed, coukd I use any symbol instead `_`?

Comment: Regarding `_` - you can use any other variable name (e.g. `value => value > 2`)

Comment: `_` is usually used when you want to show that you don't intend to use that argument. So I'd suggest you use another name, such as `value`.

Comment: I did not get how to define some filters with type `Filter`? Using the common realization?

Comment: What do you mean by "some" filters? Other than something like `(a, f) => a.filter(f)` or `(a, f) => a.filter(x => f(x))`, what are you looking for?  You could write pathological versions like `(a, f) => a` or `(a, f) => []` that violate the spirit of something named `Filter`, I guess?  What, precisely, is your question at this point, and why is it being asked in comments?